# After upgrading PySide6 gives error No module named 'PySide6.QtWidgets'

Tags: importerror, qwidget, pyside6, python-3.10

After upgrading to PySide6.3.0 getting error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6.QtWidgets'`

## source

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
label = QLabel("Hello World!")
label.show()
app.exec()
```

## error:

```
$ python3.10 test.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide6.QtWidgets'
```

Seems like there are changes in `PySide6.3.0` .

How to import `QtWidgets` module in `PySide6.3.0`?

## Edit:

It is clear it is importing PySide6 package but its not importing packages like QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10
import sys
import PySide6
from PySide6 import QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout)
from PySide6 import QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import (Qt, QSize)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    #TODO
    app.exec()
```

## output:

```
$ ./test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from PySide6 import QtWidgets
ImportError: cannot import name 'QtWidgets' from 'PySide6' (~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/__init__.py)
```

Comment: How did you update it?

Comment: @musicamante I have used `python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pyside6` command to upgrade pyside6 module

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try uninstalling PySide6 shiboken6 PySide6-Essentials PySide6-Addons and then reinstall PySide6

See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1891

Answer (score 12):

the [link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1891) provided by @Blackyy helped my resolve this issue.

> The problematic bit is because the update doesn't do a
> 'uninstall/install' and leave some files around, and doesn't override
> the PySide6 directory with the content of the new two wheels. If you
> check your site-packages you will see only like 3 modules remained.

The problem occurred when I upgraded `PySide6.2.4` to `PySide6.3.0` using

```
$ python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pyside6
```

Since we are upgrading the previous packages are left behind and will cause problem when we try to `import` modules from `pyside6`

## Solution :

```
$ python3.10 -m pip uninstall pyside6 pyside6-addons pyside6-essentials shiboken6
$ python3.10 -m pip cache purge
$ python3.10 -m pip install pyside6
```

It is necessary to clear `cache` files before reinstalling `pyside6` other wise it will use previous cache files and the `import error` using continue to come.

Comment: I've done this but I'm still getting the error
```>>> from PySide6.QtWidgets import QActionGroup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'QActionGroup' from 'PySide6.QtWidgets' (/home/Olumide/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PySide6/QtWidgets.abi3.so)```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ python3.10 -m pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir pyside6
```

No need to `pip uninstall` and `pip cache clear`